# Angular - can we bind array of objects props-value to a component which has output event?

Tags: angular

I have static placed component under a for loop.
Ex:

```
<span *ngFor="let eachFile of fileSearchList; let i = index;">    
<app-jt-input [dynamicId]="eachFile.prop" [dynamicTxt]="eachFile.txt" (searchFile{{i+1}})="onChangeInput($event)"></app-jt-input>
</span>
```

Here the **searchFile** is an output event emitter.
This doesn't work on the loop but if I do just
   search1 or search2 or search3, etc it will call onChangeInput event.

Would like to know, is it possible to do this or just have to use static part?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but why not do `(searchFile)="onChangeInput($event, i + 1)` instead?

Comment: Thanks for early response, I think will try out your solution. :)